# Django 1.5.1 support from Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am planning to make a large site and want to host it on Google App Engine using Django 1.5.1 web framework. But as I searched around the Internet I did not found any positive response about my question.

Reasons for Using Django 1.5.1-

- Django 1.5.1 is the latest Django version and Django Developers at djangoproject.org says that you would get all the bugfixes and support for these versions.
- Django 1.5.1 (and in general Django is used for large websites the great sites undoubtedly bitbucket.org , disqus.com , instagram , pinterest).

My Questions are:

- Can I add Django 1.5.1 in Google App Engine library would it work on Google App Engine?
- Should I use Google App Engine if I am hosting a site using Django 1.5.1 or I use some other PaaS for this ?
- Should I use Django 1.3 as it provides in the library of GAE ?

Comment: The latest 'included' version of django with appengine is currently 1.4, not 1.3

Comment: When you check the GAE SDK you will find 5 versions of Django (in google_appengine/lib): 0.96, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5. I'm using 1.4 with Cloud SQL. I tried to switch to 1.5 and although this appears to be working with the SDK it fails on GAE.

Comment: So It would be better to use Django 1.3 or 1.4. I also get errors after the deployment.

Comment: Probably. I'm running an app with Django 1.4 on GAE for 6 months or so without problems. If you can, go for 1.4. I have not found any reference in the Google docs that state that 1.5 is actually supported. The last time I tried it deployed ok but failed once I tried to access a page with some cryptic error in a mail package if I remember correctly.

Comment: As of November 2013 support for Django 1.5 in Google App Engine is listed as "experimental": https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you are using Cloud SQL as your backend and not the datastore, you should be able to use your own Django.  You might need to do some work in tweaking the database settings.

App Engine provides up to django 1.4, so you can use that if you don't want to install your own.

If you want to use the datastore, you'll have to use django-nonrel.  I believe there is an experimental branch that's up to 1.5 if not 1.5.1

Comment: sorry I just found your answer by google.  How would I install my own Django (1.6) in this case? Do you have any sources to show that? And is there a list of supported Django versions in GAE? Many Thanks